# Same message box text depending on any of multiple possible InputBox entries

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a `msgbox` that displays text depending on a specific entries in an `input box`.

See example code below where value entered into the `input box`, "Fantastic" or "Rubbish", gets different messages.

```vb
Dim UserAge as String
UserAge = Application.InputBox("Hi, how was your day?", Type:=3)
If InStr(1, UserAge.Text, "Fantastic") > 0 Then #runtime error '424'
    MsgBox "I am glad you are having a good day!"
ElseIf InStr(1, UserAge.Text, "Rubbish") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "I am sorry you are having a bad day!"
End If
                    
End Sub
```

To expand, I would also like to tweak the code so the same `msgbox` appears for multiple options entered e.g below.

```vb
UserAge = Application.InputBox("Hi, how was your day?", Type:=3)
If InStr(1, UserAge.Text, "Fantastic", "Excellent", "Great") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "I am glad you are having a good day!"
ElseIf InStr(1, UserAge.Text, "Rubbish","Awful") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "I am sorry you are having a bad day!"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instr` can be compared with a single text, you need to change your `or` statement as follows:

```
If InStr(1, UserAge, "Fantastic") > 0 Or InStr(1, UserAge, "Fantastic") > 0 Or InStr(1, UserAge, "Fantastic") > 0 Then
```

**However**, if you are looking for the extact phrase you entered above, you can use `Select Case` :

```
Select Case UserAge
    Case "Fantastic", "Fantastic", "Great"
        ' do something 1
        
    Case "Rubbish", "Awful"
        ' do something 2
        
End Select
```

Comment: Helpful in any case @ShaiRado +:) - fyi In my answer I demonstrated a slightly modified approach how to distinguish between different attribute groups as well as different input data types (`Type:=3 due to OP allowing text + number inputs).

Answer (score 2):

**Distinguish different groups as well as numeric vs. character input**

As OP distinguishes between

- different **groups** of attribute inputs and
- passes explicitly a **`Type:=3`** argument (accepting textual **and** numeric strings) to the `Application.InputBox()` function,

this stimulated me to demonstrate how to handle these individual specifications in the following code example.

**Example call**

Differently from VBA's `InputBox` the `Application.InputBox()` function allows to specify a *return data type*. So a `Type:=3` argument (i.e. 3 as sum of 1-number  + 2-text) in `Application.InputBox()` accepts both textual and numeric string inputs.

- See [MS Help `Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox).

```
Sub ExampleCall()
'Purp: get (case insensitive) UserInput via Application.InputBox and check response
    Dim UserAge As String
    UserAge = Application.InputBox("Hi, how was your day?", Type:=3)
    
    CheckResponse UserAge          ' << call procedure CheckResponse
End Sub
```

**Procedure `CheckResponse`**

Comprises the following steps

`[0]` Define **all** allowed attributes listed in a zero-bound array `keywords`.

```
keywords = Split("super,fantastic,great,rubbish,awful", ",")
```

`[1]` Define therein the last element number of each group (group end number):

```
Group = Array(0, 3, 5)
```

where

- [Group(0): ----------------- (= 0         )]
- Group(1): super .. great  (=3rd element)
- Group(2): rubbish..awful(=5th element)

`[2]` get the **position number** `num` within `keywords`, to be precise via `Val()` in case of *numeric* inputs or via `Application.Match()` in case of *textual* inputs. - Note how to check the validity of the position results in both cases.

`[3]` find the resulting group number based on the `num` position in `keywords`

`[4]` display the *individual* message box.

```
Sub CheckResponse(ByVal entry)
'[0]Define valid attribute inputs
    Dim keywords: keywords = Split("super,fantastic,great,rubbish,awful", ",")
'[1]Define positions of last element number within user defined groups 0/1/2:
    Dim Group(): Group = Array(0, 3, 5)
 Stop
'[2]get attribute position within keywords (1-based)
    Dim num As Variant
    If Val(entry) Then      ' a) numeric input
        num = Val(entry)
        If num > Group(UBound(Group)) Then num = 0
    Else                    ' b) characters = textual input
        num = Application.Match(entry, keywords, 0)
        If Not IsNumeric(num) Then num = 0
    End If

'[3]get group number
    Dim GroupNum As Long
    Select Case num
    Case Group(0)
        MsgBox "Input " & entry & " not found!", vbCritical, "Invalid Attribute"
    Case Is <= Group(1)
        GroupNum = 1
    Case Is <= Group(2)
        GroupNum = 2
    End Select
    
'[4]display message
    If GroupNum Then
        MsgBox "**My day was " & _
               keywords(num - 1) & ".**" & String(2, vbNewLine) & _
               "(Identified as " & _
               num - Group(GroupNum - 1) & ". item in " & _
               GroupNum & ". group)", vbInformation, "My Response"
    End If
End Sub
```

Have fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

### `If` Statement Practice feat. `Application.InputBox`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exSimple()

    Dim UserAge As Variant
    UserAge = Application.InputBox("Hi, how was your day?", Type:=2)
    
    If UserAge = False Then
        MsgBox "You canceled."
    ElseIf InStr(1, UserAge, "Fantastic", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "I am glad you are having a good day!"
    ElseIf InStr(1, UserAge, "Rubbish", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "I am sorry you are having a bad day!"
    'Else
        ' Non of the above.
    End If

End Sub


Sub exAdvanced()

    Dim UserAge As Variant
    UserAge = Application.InputBox("Hi, how was your day?", Type:=2)
    
    If UserAge = False Then
        MsgBox "You canceled."
    ElseIf InStr(1, UserAge, "Rubbish", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "I am sorry you are having a bad day!"
    Else
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Fantastic", "Excellent", "Great")
        Dim n As Long
        For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(1, UserAge, arr(n), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
        If n <= UBound(arr) Then
            MsgBox "I am glad you are having a good day!"
        'Else
            'none of the above
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```